# I have monthly data, is there a quick way for slicing the indices and plotting?

Tags: python

I have monthly data and I want to plot only certain regions, every 24 steps (2 years) or so, how can I find a quick way to plot every 20 steps using a for loop maybe?
For example, instead of doing this:

```
#first 24 indices
plt.plot(time_months[0:24], monthly[0:24])
plt.xticks(rotation=35)
plt.show()

#next set of 24 indices
plt.plot(time_months[24:48], monthly[24:48])
plt.xticks(rotation=35)
plt.show()
```

I tried this:

```
for i in range(monthly.size):
    plt.plot(time_months[0:i,24])
plt.show()
```

but I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-db04910853f1> in <module>
      4 
      5 for i in range(monthly.size):
----> 6     plt.plot(time_months[0:24,i])
      7 plt.show()

IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts, that's no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A naive solution can be the following if you know how many steps ie. (0-24), (24-48).....(n-24,n) are possible for your case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
b = [ i*0.1 for i in a]

number_of_steps = 3

for i in range(number_of_steps):
    plt.plot(a[i*number_of_steps:(i+1)*number_of_steps],b[i*number_of_steps:(i+1)*number_of_steps])
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i will change my answer to reflect it

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, the answers above do not answer the question. This one works properly:

```
for i in range(int(len(lsds_monthly)/24)):
    plt.plot(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24],lsds_monthly[i*24: (i+1)*24])
    plt.xticks(np.arange(min(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),max(time_months[i*24: (i+1)*24]),.15), rotation=35)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```